# How to avoid restarting the server when changing I18n translations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a Rails 4 app where I'm trying to enable translations to be entered using the [I18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record) backend.

Everything seems to be working ok, but after adding or changing one of the translations, it requires a restart of the server in order for the updated translations to show in the views.

How can I configure the app so that a translation shown in a view is always getting the latest information in the db without having to restart the server?

I can do this in my controller:

```
 if @translation.update(translation_params)
    I18n.backend.reload!
    redirect_to translations_url
 else
    render :edit, alert: 'There was a problem:'
 end
```

But is there a "cleaner" way of doing this?

Comment: it is the cleanest way

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems fine to me as there doesn't seem to be any method of reloading only the updated translation key (which I would consider to be the best solution).

If you enabled i18n cache, you could clear it with `I18n.cache_store.clear` when a translation is updated.